# ngrx update object inside array

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-reducers

I have a ngrx store with array of objects. What I am looking for is, update(modify) the object inside the array using the array index.
My ngrx data will look like,

```
    policies: {
        beneficiaries: {
            beneficiaries: [{
                    name: 'pqr'
                    age: 56
                },
                {
                    name: 'xyz'
                    age: 76
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I have to update the beneficiary name based on the array index.
So I have implemented the following reducer function

```
    on(policiesActions.updateBeneficiaryPercentage, (state, action) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          beneficiaries: {
            ...state.beneficiaries,
            beneficiaries: {
              ...state.beneficiaries.beneficiaries,
              [action.index]: {
                ...state.beneficiaries.beneficiaries[action.index],
                name: action.value
              }
            }
          }
        };
      })
```

The issue with the above code is that 
after running this code the structure of my store is changing to

```
policies: {
    beneficiaries: {
        beneficiaries: {
            0: {
                name: 'pqr'
                age: 1000
            },
            1: {
                name: 'xyz'
                age: 76
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix the code so that I can update the value without altering the store structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When updating an object in array, I would re-create an array with all excluded objects and append last object which needs updated value.

```js
const policies = {
  beneficiaries: {
    beneficiaries: [{
        name: 'pqr',
        age: 56
      },
      {
        name: 'xyz',
        age: 76
      }
    ]
  }
}

const updateObject = (state, action) => {

  if(!state.beneficiaries.beneficiaries[action.index]) {
    return state;
  }

  return {
    ...state,
    beneficiaries: {
      ...state.beneficiaries,
      beneficiaries: [
        ...state.beneficiaries.beneficiaries.slice(0, action.index),
        {
          ...state.beneficiaries.beneficiaries[action.index],
          name: action.value
        },
        ...state.beneficiaries.beneficiaries.slice(action.index + 1)
      ]
    }
  };
}

console.log(updateObject(policies, {index: 1, value: 'test'}))
```

--Edit

Added the snippet and changed the logic so it doesnt change list order.

Comment: This one is working... but the order of array elements are changing... That is the updated element will become the last element in the array...

Comment: Updated an answer. Yeah that didn't make sense at all when new state changes the order of list.

Answer (score 17):

Use the `Array.map` method:

```
arr.map((value, index) => index === action.index ? {...value, name: action.value} : value)
```

Or just use [ngrx-etc](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-etc), which lets you mutate your state in a mutable way while remaining immutable

```
mutableOn(onAction, (state, action) => {
  state.arr[action.index].name = action.name
  return state
})
```

Comment: `ngrx-etc` is an awesome library, sparing the developer from writing cumbersome code in some cases. This is particularly useful when items order in the array should not be altered. Thanks.

Comment: Just to note that ngrx-etc has been superceeded by ngrx-immer ( https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer )

Answer (score 8):

This is an easy way without resorting to deep diving into the state object.

```
on(ProductActions.updateProductSuccess, (state, action): ProductState => {

  // define a constant and map over the existing state, inserting your new item,
  // then assign your new object as the new state.

  const updatedProducts = state.products.map(
  product => action.product.id === product.id ? action.product : product);
  return {
    ...state,
    products: updatedProducts
  
   };
}),
```

This assumes you are passing a complete product object in your success action.

Answer (score 4):

You can use immer.js to generate a new state without touching the previous state. No need to roll your own solution, plus recreating the object by cloning the previous one manually is *error prone*.

```js
import produce from "immer"

on(policiesActions.updateBeneficiaryPercentage, (state, action) => {
  return produce(state, draftState => {
    draftState.policies.beneficiaries.beneficiaries[action.index].name = action.value
  })
})
```

If you want to do it in a functional way you may try lenses [example using ramda](https://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/07/12/thinking-in-ramda-lenses/)